# Printing a JSON object in hierarchical/tree format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tree

**Object:**

```
[
   {
      "Item":{
         "Name":"User 4"
      },
      "Children":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "Item":{
         "Name":"User 1"
      },
      "Children":[
         {
            "Item":{
               "Name":"User 6"
            }
         },
         {
            "Item":{
               "Name":"User 2"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am traversing this object with the following code:

```
(function Traverse(o) {
    for (var i in o) {
        console.log('Value: ' + o[i].Item.Name);

        if (o[i].Children !== null && o[i].Children !== [] && typeof(o[i].Children) == "object") {
            Traverse(o[i].Children);
        }
    }
  })
(data);
```

Output:

```
value: User 4
value: User 1
value: User 6
value: User 2
undefined
```

I want the output to be in a hierarchal/tree format. I have found several libraries but I do not want a proper graphical representation, just a simple use of text to indicate the hierarchy.

Something like this:

[image]

P.S. I am not a javascript programmer.

Comment: I am getting output `user 4, user 1, user 6, user 2` from your code. Isn;t the same you want ?

Comment: @amar_1995 sorry, I forgot to write the updated output. But I am interested in getting the output in hierarchal/tree format as shown in the image above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this recursive function. As an example I have used an object with a bit more items and levels:

```js
function toText(arr) {
    const recur = ({Item, Children}) => Item?.Name + 
        (Children?.length ? "\n" + Children.map(recur).map((text, i, {length}) =>
            i < length-1 ? "├──" + text.replace(/\n/g, "\n│  ")
                         : "└──" + text.replace(/\n/g, "\n   ")
        ).join("\n") : "")
    return arr.map(recur).join("\n");
}

// Example:
let arr = [{
    "Item": {
        "Name": "A"
    },
    "Children": [
    ]
}, {
    "Item": {
        "Name": "B"
    },
    "Children": [{
        "Item": {
           "Name": "BA"
        },
        "Children": [{
            "Item": {
                "Name": "BAA"
            },
            "Children": [{
                "Item": {
                    "Name": "BAAA"
                }
            }, {
                "Item": {
                    "Name": "BAAB"
                }
            }, {
                "Item": {
                    "Name": "BAAC"
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "Item": {
                "Name": "BAB"
            },
            "Children": [{
                "Item": {
                    "Name": "BABA"
                }
            }]
       }]
    }, {
        "Item":{
            "Name": "BB"
        }
    }]
}];
console.log(toText(arr));
```

Comment: Awesome!  You can display the result in a div with something like `<div id='output'></div>` setting CSS like `#output{white-space:pre; font-family:monospace;}`, populating it with JavaScript such as `output.innerHTML=toText(arr);`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I found the format is kinda broken when code is executed in snippet. If you paste the code to the devtools and run it, the format is correct.

I found a npm package [oo-ascii-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oo-ascii-tree) to do this. Here is an example for your requirement:

```js
/**
 * A tree of nodes that can be ASCII visualized.
 */
class AsciiTree {
    /**
     * Creates a node.
     * @param text The node's text content
     * @param children Children of this node (can also be added via "add")
     */
    constructor(text, ...children) {
        this.text = text;
        this._children = new Array();
        for (const child of children) {
            this.add(child);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Prints the tree to an output stream.
     */
    printTree(output = process.stdout) {
        let ancestorsPrefix = '';
        for (const parent of this.ancestors) {
            // -1 represents a "hidden" root, and so it's children
            // will all appear as roots (level 0).
            if (parent.level <= 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (parent.last) {
                ancestorsPrefix += '  ';
            }
            else {
                ancestorsPrefix += ' │';
            }
        }
        let myPrefix = '';
        let multilinePrefix = '';
        if (this.level > 0) {
            if (this.last) {
                if (!this.empty) {
                    myPrefix += ' └─┬ ';
                    multilinePrefix += ' └─┬ ';
                }
                else {
                    myPrefix += ' └── ';
                    multilinePrefix = '     ';
                }
            }
            else {
                if (!this.empty) {
                    myPrefix += ' ├─┬ ';
                    multilinePrefix += ' │ │ ';
                }
                else {
                    myPrefix += ' ├── ';
                    multilinePrefix += ' │   ';
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.text) {
            output.write(ancestorsPrefix);
            output.write(myPrefix);
            const lines = this.text.split('\n');
            output.write(lines[0]);
            output.write('\n');
            for (const line of lines.splice(1)) {
                output.write(ancestorsPrefix);
                output.write(multilinePrefix);
                output.write(line);
                output.write('\n');
            }
        }
        for (const child of this._children) {
            child.printTree(output);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the tree.
     */
    toString() {
        let out = '';
        this.printTree({
            write: (data) => (out += data),
        });
        return out;
    }
    /**
     * Adds children to the node.
     */
    add(...children) {
        for (const child of children) {
            child.parent = this;
            this._children.push(child);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns a copy of the children array.
     */
    get children() {
        return this._children.map((x) => x);
    }
    /**
     * @returns true if this is the root node
     */
    get root() {
        return !this.parent;
    }
    /**
     * @returns true if this is the last child
     */
    get last() {
        if (!this.parent) {
            return true;
        }
        return (this.parent.children.indexOf(this) === this.parent.children.length - 1);
    }
    /**
     * @returns the node level (0 is the root node)
     */
    get level() {
        if (!this.parent) {
            // if the root node does not have text, it will be considered level -1
            // so that all it's children will be roots.
            return this.text ? 0 : -1;
        }
        return this.parent.level + 1;
    }
    /**
     * @returns true if this node does not have any children
     */
    get empty() {
        return this.children.length === 0;
    }
    /**
     * @returns an array of parent nodes (from the root to this node, exclusive)
     */
    get ancestors() {
        if (!this.parent) {
            return [];
        }
        return [...this.parent.ancestors, this.parent];
    }
}

const arrEg = [
   {
      "Item":{
         "Name":"User 4"
      },
      "Children":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "Item":{
         "Name":"User 1"
      },
      "Children":[
         {
            "Item":{
               "Name":"User 6"
            }
         },
         {
            "Item":{
               "Name":"User 2"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
];

function obj2tree(obj, tree) {
    const subTree = new AsciiTree(`${obj.Item.Name}`);
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty("Children")){
    obj.Children.forEach(o => {
        obj2tree(o, subTree);
    });
   }
  tree.add(subTree);
}

const treeStr = (objarr => {
    const tree = new AsciiTree('root');
    objarr.forEach(obj => {
    obj2tree(obj, tree);
   });
   return tree.toString();
})(arrEg);

console.log(treeStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan): Convert the input into a tree structure first and then use an [existing library](https://github.com/blackflux/object-treeify) of your choice to convert it into the tree representations.

Upside is that this solution does not use recursion (even under the hood) - so stack overflows should be impossible for deeply nested data.

Note that name collisions will automatically get merged. So depending on if that is desired I also did like the solution @trincot posted.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');
// const objectTreeify = require('object-treeify');

const data = [ { Item: { Name: 'A' }, Children: [] }, { Item: { Name: 'B' }, Children: [ { Item: { Name: 'BA' }, Children: [ { Item: { Name: 'BAA' }, Children: [ { Item: { Name: 'BAAA' } }, { Item: { Name: 'BAAB' } }, { Item: { Name: 'BAAC' } } ] }, { Item: { Name: 'BAB' }, Children: [ { Item: { Name: 'BABA' } } ] } ] }, { Item: { Name: 'BB' } } ] } ];

const treeify = (input) => {
  const tree = objectScan(['**[*]'], {
    reverse: false,
    breakFn: ({ isMatch, value, context }) => {
      if (isMatch) {
        const cur = context[context.length - 1];
        const name = value.Item.Name;
        if (!(name in cur)) {
          cur[name] = {};
        }
        context.push(cur[name]);
      }
    },
    filterFn: ({ context }) => {
      context.pop();
    }
  })(input, [{}])[0];
  return objectTreeify(tree);
};

console.log(treeify(data));
/* =>
├─ A
└─ B
   ├─ BA
   │  ├─ BAA
   │  │  ├─ BAAA
   │  │  ├─ BAAB
   │  │  └─ BAAC
   │  └─ BAB
   │     └─ BABA
   └─ BB
 */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-treeify@1.1.31"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan) and [object-treeify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-treeify)